# Problem running application on windows server 2008 instance using amazon ec2 service and WAMP

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2

I have a basic (small type) windows server 2008 instance running on amazon ec2. I've installed WAMP server on to it, and have also loaded my application. I did this using Remote desktop Connection from my windows machine. I'm able to run my application locally on the instance, however when I try to access it using the public DNS given to it by amazon, from my browser, I'm unable to do so, I end up getting a request timed out error.

My instance has a security group that is configured to allow HTTP, HTTPS, RDP, SSH and SMTP requests on different ports. In fact I have the exact same security group as the one used in this blog, http://howto.opml.org/dave/ec2/

I did almost everything same as the blog, except for using a different Amazon Machine Image. 
I've tried pinging the address but that doesn't seem to work either. I get a request timed out error both times

This is my first time using amazon ec2, and i can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instance has the required ports open at the (virtual) perimeter firewall level, but what about the software firewall that's built into Windows?  Try going into Control Panel and temporarily disabling Windows Firewall for testing purposes.  At that point, are your services available from a remote client?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to connect to the server after disabling the firewall.

Comment: always forget to open the windows firewall, thanks for the hint